# Using VirtualBox with minikube in Mac crashes

Tags: docker, virtualbox, minikube, macos-ventura

I'm running this command that worked before in version 11 of mac os to launch a minikube cluster

`minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox -p myminikube`

and I'm getting this error

`Exiting due to IF_VBOX_NOT_VISIBLE: Failed to start host: driver start: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue`

However, by VirtualBox version is 7.0.10. I can also access to VirtualBox machines, the problem is only when running this minikube command.

Also, my network is not using host only, I just have configured `Adapter 1: Paravirtualized Network (NAT)`
My current version of applications that might be relevant are

- macOS: Ventura 13.6
- VirtualBox: 7.0.10
- docker: 20.10.8
- minikube: 1.24.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [open Github issue](https://github.com/machine-drivers/machine/issues/38) : Many users on minikube unable to use the VirtualBox driver on macOS 13 or later. This is due to Host-only Adapter being deprecated, it will need to be replaced with [Host-only Network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly).

**Workaround :** Host only adapters are no longer supported on Mac. Run **podman** until we get a VB driver update. Run commands like below ;

`brew install podman`

`podman machine init --cpus 2 --memory 2048 --rootful`

`podman machine start`

`minikube config set driver podman`

`minikube start`

`minikube status`

Use another driver, such as the [QEMU driver](https://github.com/afbjorklund/docker-machine-driver-qemu) - that also supports ARM, not only Intel (if using minikube, there is a "qemu2" driver there).